# Parallel computation of values for `ndarray` `Array2<f64>` in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex, rayon, rust-ndarray

I am trying to speed up my calculations and I am not sure, how to best use `.into_par_iter()` or some of the `Zip::` options from the `ndarray` crate in order to "correctly" parallelize the computation to speed up things.

I have tried 2 ways, but I think due to my understanding of `Mutex` the whole Array gets "locked", which just creates more overhead and the calculations are slower than before.

1. example:

```rust
//* Step 2.1: Calculate the overlap matrix S
let S_matr_tmp = Array2::<f64>::zeros((n, n));
let S_matr_mutex = Mutex::new(S_matr_tmp);

(0..n).into_par_iter().for_each(|i| {
    (0..=i).into_par_iter().for_each(|j| {
        let mut s = S_matr_mutex.lock().unwrap();
        if i == j {
            s[(i, j)] = 1.0;
            // s = 1.0;
        } else {
            s[(i, j)] = calc_overlap_int_cgto(
                &self.mol.wfn_total.basis_set_total.basis_set_cgtos[i],
                &self.mol.wfn_total.basis_set_total.basis_set_cgtos[j],
            );
            s[(j, i)] = s[(i, j)];
        }
    })
});

self.mol.wfn_total.HF_Matrices.S_matr = S_matr_mutex.into_inner().unwrap();
```

2. example:

```rust
let D_matr_mutex = Mutex::new(Array2::<f64>::zeros((no_cgtos, no_cgtos)));

//* D^0 matrix */
//* Trying to parallelize it */
Zip::indexed(C_matr_AO_basis.axis_iter(Axis(0))).par_for_each(|mu, row1| {
    Zip::indexed(C_matr_AO_basis.outer_iter()).par_for_each(|nu, row2| {
        let mut d = D_matr_mutex.lock().unwrap();
        let slice1 = row1.slice(s![..no_occ_orb]);
        let slice2 = row2.slice(s![..no_occ_orb]);
        d[(mu, nu)] = slice1.dot(&slice2);
    });
});

let mut D_matr = D_matr_mutex.into_inner().unwrap();
```

3. example (most important code to parallelize):

```rust
let F_matr_mutex = Mutex::new(F_matr);

(0..no_cgtos).into_par_iter().for_each(|mu| {
    (0..no_cgtos).into_par_iter().for_each(|nu| {
        (0..no_cgtos).into_par_iter().for_each(|lambda| {
            (0..no_cgtos).into_par_iter().for_each(|sigma| {
                let mu_nu_lambda_sigma =
                    calc_ijkl_idx(mu + 1, nu + 1, lambda + 1, sigma + 1);
                let mu_lambda_nu_sigma =
                    calc_ijkl_idx(mu + 1, lambda + 1, nu + 1, sigma + 1);
                let mut f = F_matr_mutex.lock().unwrap();
                f[(mu, nu)] += D_matr[(lambda, sigma)]
                    * (2.0
                        * self.mol.wfn_total.HF_Matrices.ERI_arr1[mu_nu_lambda_sigma]
                        - self.mol.wfn_total.HF_Matrices.ERI_arr1[mu_lambda_nu_sigma]);
            });
        });
    });
});

let F_matr = F_matr_mutex.into_inner().unwrap();
```

Any help on how to parallelize the code "correctly" and more information on how to use `Mutex` better would be appreciated.

Comment: I also asked this question in the `Q&A` section in the `ndarray` repo on GitHub, so if anyone is searching for something like this. You can look here: https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/discussions/1273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @adamreichold I was able to understand more about my problem and then "correctly" parallelized my code which led to a noticable speed-up of my calculations.

Now to the explaination:

1. My problem was, that I was trying to figure out a way to parallelize the `for` loops "as is".
2. `ndarray` can be used in the "classical" way with `for` loops, but seems to be more efficient in the functional programming way, in the sense that you are apply e.g. a `for_each` directly on a `object` instead of looping with indices and then accessing fields with the indices.
3. Functional seemed the way to go; including the correct usage of `Zip::` methods.

'Better' verison for example 1:

```rust
//* New version: par_for_each and indexed */
self.mol.wfn_total.HF_Matrices.S_matr = Array2::<f64>::zeros((n, n));

Zip::indexed(&mut self.mol.wfn_total.HF_Matrices.S_matr).par_for_each(|(i, j), s_val| {
    if i == j {
        *s_val = 1.0;
    } else if i >= j {
        //* Calculate only lower triangle matrix */
        *s_val = calc_overlap_int_cgto(
            &self.mol.wfn_total.basis_set_total.basis_set_cgtos[i],
            &self.mol.wfn_total.basis_set_total.basis_set_cgtos[j],
        )
    } else {
        *s_val = 0.0;
    }
});

// * Assign lower triangle to upper triangle with slices -> larger chunks
for i in 0..n - 1 {
    let slice = self
        .mol
        .wfn_total
        .HF_Matrices
        .S_matr
        .slice(s![i + 1..n, i])
        .to_shared();
    self.mol
        .wfn_total
        .HF_Matrices
        .S_matr
        .slice_mut(s![i, i + 1..n])
        .assign(&slice);
}
```

Small explaination of the code:

1. `Zip::indexed` needs a `&mut arr` to index the `arr` and the `par_for_each` goes through all the elements with a `par_iter`.
2. `(i,j)` are the 2 indices that are needed to index into the `basis_set_cgtos` (which is a `Vec`)
3. Computation time is saved as only the lower triangle matrix is calculated and then copied to the upper half, so we are basically saying:

[image: formula]

The rest of the examples can be parallelized analogously (code in my GitHub repo: [SCF_MRJD_RS](https://github.com/MartinRJDagleish/SCF_MRJD_RS))